# Высчитать оставшийся срок в процентах

Tags: php

Есть начальная дата, и конечная. Например: 30.05.2018 — 30.10.2018

Как высчитать сколько % уже прошло от начальной даты до конечной. То есть - 30.05.2018 - это 0% , 30.10.2018 - это 100%.

P.S. дата дата для примера, она может быть любой.

Comment: А какой шаг, я так понимаю у вас 5 месяцев = 100%? т.е. нужно брать количество дней и от них уже считать процент?

Comment: @RifmaMan , можно по кол-ву дней, можно по кол-ву оставшихся месяцев. тут не так важно точность, это для наглядности делается, главное чтобы правдоподобно считало :)

Comment: Переведите в размерную величину, которая подлежит вычитанию. Например в к-во годов, к-во месяцев,  или к-во дней - тогда и % будет понятно как считать. Если есть А и Б, и есть С между ними, то будет вам `% = (100 * (Б-А)) / (Б - С) ;` алгебра чистой воды.

Comment: @nick_n_a ну к примеру если высчитать от сегодняшней даты `(потому что начальная дата всегда будет текущая дата)` оставшееся кол-во дней до конечно даты, как в таком случае высчитать % ?

Comment: Процент можно посчитать только если есть три точки. Или если третья точка ноль. Вы можете конечно одну из точек взять как ноль - тогда результат у вас будет либо 0,0001% либо 99,999%

Comment: % показывает пропорцию. Допустим 50% - это когда от начального периода до сейчас расстояние равно расстоянию от сейчас до конечного периода.

Answer (score 1):

Сформировать три метки времени с помощью mktime и вычислить отношение, как в пятом классе учили:

```
 $tend = mktime(0, 0, 0, 10, 30, 2018);
 ...
 $percent = 100 * ($tnow - $tstart) / ($tend - $tstart))
```

Comment: `tnow` и `tstart` - это что за переменные?

Comment: текущая и начальные даты

Answer (score 1):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('30.05.2018');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('30.10.2018');
$datetimenow = new DateTime();
$interval100 = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$interval = $datetimenow->diff($datetime2);
$result = $interval * 100 / $interval100;
```

Comment: Вот вам пример трёх точек `% = (100 * (Б-А)) / (Б - С) ;` А=30.05.2018 Б=30.10.2018 и С=сейчас. Возможно знак в ответе напутан, мне казалось надо от большего отнимать меньшее.. ну это мелочи. Знак сократится при делении)))

Comment: @nick_n_a Простите а где в этом коде вы нашли знаки?

Comment: После вычитания diff.

Comment: Я перепутал делители внизу большее `% = (100 * (Б-С)) / (Б - А) ;` и слева большее число. Но можно и так `% = (100 * (С-Б)) / (А-Б) ;`  просто знак сократится.

Comment: @nick_n_a Так в коде это и написано.